# Jackson deserializer with multiple levels of polymorphic type hierachy

Tags: java, json, polymorphism, jackson, deserialization

It seems that this use case is not supported:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=B1.class, name="b1"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=B2.class, name="b2")
})
public abstract class A {
    ...
}

public class B1 extends A {
    ...
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "subtype")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=C1.class, name="c1"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=C2.class, name="c2")
})
public abstract class B2 extends A {
    ...
}

public class C1 extends B2 {
    ...
}

public class C2 extends B2 {
    ...
}
```

What I want is to resolve this one: { "type": "b1"; ... } to class B1, and { "type": "b2";  "subtype": "c1"; ... } to class C1 and { "type": "b2"; "subtype": "c2"; ... } to class C2.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you specify all subtypes in class A annotations?

Comment: Well, look at the concrete classes: B1, C1, and C2. B1 has the "type" property equals "b1" and no "subtype" property. while C1 and C2 are with the same "type" property and different "subtype" property. how can I achieve this by specify all subtypes in class A annotations?

Comment: Do you need both type and subtype? type=c1 is a sufficient information for the demarshalling.

Comment: Yes, both type and subtype are there, I am just deserializing from something which is not under my control, I can't change the format of the received message.

Answer (score 1):

For those who need the answer, OP got an answer [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/374#issuecomment-31212775):

> This is not supported