Polymorphic deserialization of Multiple level inheritance through Jackson in Java
How do I deserialize the following example so that Jackson automatically provides me with the correct object
public class vehicle {
String vehicleType;
}

public class car extends vehicle {
String carType;
String make;
}

public class sedan extends car {
String model;
}

What I ideally want is to pass a json structure to the following code and for and object of the correct subtype be created.
For eg:
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        vehicle myVehicle = mapper.readValue(inputData, vehicle.class);
        Assertions.assertInstanceOf(sedan.class, myVehicle);

The above test should hold true for the following json data
{
"vehicleType" : "car",
"carType" : "sedan",
"make" : "Foo",
"model" : "Bar"
}

I can get upto 1 level of inheritance correctly using something to the effect of
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "vehicleType")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = car.class, name = "car")
})
public class vehicle {...}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "carType")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = sedan.class, name = "sedan")
})
public class car extends vehicle {...}

public class sedan extends car {...}


When I run the above code, I get an object of type car, and not an object of type sedan.

I found a similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742213/jackson-deserializer-with-multiple-levels-of-polymorphic-type-hierachy

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/374#issuecomment-31212775
FEATURE IS NOT SUPPORTED

If you really need this to work, you could probably do it reasonably with reflection, but it doesn't appear that Jackson will do this automagically for you.

You need to list all sub-types in vehicle.
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "vehicleType")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = car.class, name = "car"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = sedan.class, name = "sedan")
})
public class vehicle {...}

